# How to count number of positive solutions of an equation $x_1 + x_2 +...+ x_n = s$ where $0 < x_i \le c $.

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

- I want to solve the equation:
  $$
  x_1 + x_2 +...+ x_n = s \\
  \text{where }\ 0 < x_i \le c 
  $$
- Or to rephrase the question count number of ways to break number $s$ in to $n$ numbers where each number is between $1$ to $c$.
- Without upper bound $x_i < c$ I can use stars and bars method. But since i have upper limit can i still use same method with some modification? Or can you reference me to some other method which can help me solve this.

Comment: @Mike Earnest I read your answer in the link. Its really helpful. But i am not sure how the equation will change since i have $xi>0$ and in your answer its $xi≥0$. Just $n$ will be removed from top?

Comment: @poojan124 If you want $x_i \ge 1$, write $x_i = 1 + t_i$ and that becomes $t_i \ge 0$.

Comment: Consider the generating expression that is the coefficient of $x^s$ in $(x+x^2+x^3\dots+x^c)^n$.